# Using fgets and strtok() to read a text file -C

Tags: c, fgets, strtok

I’m trying to read text from stdin line by line using fgets() and store the text in a variable “text”. However, when I use strtok() to split the words, it only works for a couple lines before terminating. What should I change to make it run through the entire text?

```
#define WORD_BUFFER_SIZE 50
#define TEXT_SIZE 200

int main(void) {
    char stopWords[TEXT_SIZE][WORD_BUFFER_SIZE];
    char word[WORD_BUFFER_SIZE];
    int numberOfWords = 0;
  
    while(scanf("%s", word) == 1){
      if (strcmp(word, "====") == 0){
        break;
      }
      strcpy(stopWords[numberOfWords], word);
      numberOfWords++;
    }

  char *buffer = malloc(sizeof(WORD_BUFFER_SIZE)*TEXT_SIZE);
  char *text = malloc(sizeof(WORD_BUFFER_SIZE)*TEXT_SIZE);
  
  while(fgets(buffer, WORD_BUFFER_SIZE*TEXT_SIZE, stdin) != NULL){  
    strcat(text, buffer);
  }
  
  char *k;
  k = strtok(text, " ");
  while (k != NULL) {
    printf("%s\n", k);
    k = strtok(NULL, " ");
  }
  
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] (which includes a function `main` and all `#include` and `#define` directives) and specify exactly the input, expected output and actual output.

Comment: Before using `strtok`, you may want to print the result of the `fgets` and `strcat` operations, in order to verify that it is correct. What happens when you insert the line `printf( "text contents: %s\n\n", text );` between the second and third `while` loop?

Comment: A few lines of sample input would be nice. There may be an easier way.

Comment: What value do you expect `sizeof(WORD_BUFFER_SIZE)` to have? That it simply `sizeof(int)`, which is `4` on most platforms.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel I tried this. It store the entire text.

Comment: The function `strcat` requires a null-termined string as its first parameter. However, on the first call to the function, the content of the memory pointed to by the first parameter is indeterminate. This caused undefined behavior. Therefore, you should initialize it before the first call to `strcat`.

Comment: Are you reading from a file? Is `text` longer than 800 characters? If it is, then you have a [buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow), because you have only allocated 800 characters for it. Please provide a [mre] with the exact input. Also, it would be nice if you also posted all necessary `#include` directives. Otherwise, it will be more work for other people to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani It should not be there. I removed it

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Yes, the text is longer than 800 characters. Due to the policy, I’m not allowed to post the input file here. The input has 2 parts, separated by “====“. The first part is the stopwords (I already handled it). The second part is the text which only has spaces as delimiter. I initially used sscanf in fgets loop, but I couldn’t figure out how to tokenize the text.

Comment: @RandomDev: If you cannot provide your real input, then please provide a few lines of made-up sample input, so that we can at least test our solutions. Please [edit] your question to provide this input.

Answer (score 2):

```
char *buffer = malloc(sizeof(WORD_BUFFER_SIZE)*TEXT_SIZE);
char *text = malloc(sizeof(WORD_BUFFER_SIZE)*TEXT_SIZE);
```

`sizeof(WORD_BUFFER_SIZE)` is a constant, it's the size of integer. You probably mean `WORD_BUFFER_SIZE * TEXT_SIZE`. But you can find the file size and calculate exactly how much memory you need.

```
char *text = malloc(...)
strcat(text, buffer);
```

`text` is not initialized and doesn't have a null-terminator. `strcat` needs to know the end of `text`. You have to set `text[0] = '\0'` before using `strcat` (it's not like `strcpy`)

```
int main(void) 
{
    fseek(stdin, 0, SEEK_END);
    size_t filesize = ftell(stdin);
    rewind(stdin);
    if (filesize == 0)
    { printf("not using a file!\n"); return 0; }

    char word[1000] = { 0 };

    //while (scanf("%s", word) != 1)
    //    if (strcmp(word, "====") == 0)
    //        break;

    char* text = malloc(filesize + 1);
    if (!text)
        return 0;
    text[0] = '\0';
    while (fgets(word, sizeof(word), stdin) != NULL)
        strcat(text, word);

    char* k;
    k = strtok(text, " ");
    while (k != NULL) 
    {
        printf("%s\n", k);
        k = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the information you provided in the comments section, the input text is longer than 800 bytes.

However, in the line

```
char *text = malloc(sizeof(WORD_BUFFER_SIZE)*TEXT_SIZE);
```

which is equivalent to

```
char *text = malloc(800);
```

you only allocated 800 bytes as storage for `text`. Therefore, you did not allocate sufficient space to store the entire input into `text`. Attempting to store more than 800 bytes will result in a [buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow), which invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

If you want to store the entire input into `text`, then you must ensure that it is large enough.

However, this is probably not necessary. Depending on your requirements, it is probably sufficient to process one line at a time, like this:

```
while( fgets( buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin ) != NULL )
{
    char *k = strtok( buffer, " " );

    while ( k != NULL )
    {
        printf( "%s\n", k );
        k = strtok( NULL, " " );
    }
}
```

In that case, you do not need the array `text`. You only need the array `buffer` for storing the current contents of the line.

Since you did not provide any sample input, I cannot test the code above.

---

EDIT: Based on your comments to this answer, it seems that your main problem is how to read in all of the input from `stdin` and store it as a string, when you do not know the length of the input in advance.

One common solution is to allocate an initial buffer, and to double its size every time it gets full. You can use the function [`realloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc) for this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( void )
{
    char *buffer;
    size_t buffer_size = 1024;
    size_t input_size = 0;

    //allocate initial buffer
    buffer = malloc( buffer_size );
    if ( buffer == NULL )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "allocation error!\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    //continuously fill the buffer with input, and
    //grow buffer as necessary
    for (;;) //infinite loop, equivalent to while(1)
    {
        //we must leave room for the terminating null character
        size_t to_read = buffer_size - input_size - 1;
        size_t ret;

        ret = fread( buffer + input_size, 1, to_read, stdin );

        input_size += ret;

        if ( ret != to_read )
        {
            //we have finished reading from input
            break;
        }

        //buffer was filled entirely (except for the space
        //reserved for the terminating null character), so
        //we must grow the buffer
        {
            void *temp;

            buffer_size *= 2;
            temp = realloc( buffer, buffer_size );

            if ( temp == NULL )
            {
                fprintf( stderr, "allocation error!\n" );
                exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
            }

            buffer = temp;
        }
    }

    //make sure that `fread` did not fail end due to
    //error (it should only end due to end-of-file)
    if ( ferror(stdin) )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "input error!\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    //add terminating null character
    buffer[input_size++] = '\0';

    //shrink buffer to required size
    {
        void *temp;

        temp = realloc( buffer, input_size );

        if ( temp == NULL )
        {
            fprintf( stderr, "allocation error!\n" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        buffer = temp;
    }

    //the entire contents is now stored in "buffer" as a
    //string, and can be printed
    printf( "contents of buffer:\n%s\n", buffer );

    free( buffer );
}
```

The code above assumes that the input will be terminated by an end of file condition, which is probably the case if the input is piped from a file.

On second thought, instead of having one large string for the whole file, as you are doing in your code, you may rather want an array of `char*` to the individual strings, each representing a line, so that for example `lines[0]` will be the string of the first line, `lines[1]` will be the string of the second line. That way, you can easily use [`strstr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strstr) to find the " ==== " deliminator and [`strchr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strchr) on each individual line to find the individual words, and still have all the lines in memory for further processing.

I don't recommend that you use [`strtok`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) in this case, because that function is destructive in the sense that it modifies the string, by replacing the deliminators with null characters. If you require the strings for further processing, as you stated in the comments section, then this is probably not what you want. That is why I recommend that you use `strchr` instead.

If a reasonable maximum number of lines is known at compile-time, then the solution is rather easy:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LINE_LENGTH 1024
#define MAX_LINES 1024

int main( void )
{
    char *lines[MAX_LINES];
    int num_lines = 0;

    char buffer[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];

    //read one line per loop iteration
    while ( fgets( buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin ) != NULL )
    {
        int line_length = strlen( buffer );

        //verify that entire line was read in
        if ( buffer[line_length-1] != '\n' )
        {
            //treat end-of file as equivalent to newline character
            if ( !feof( stdin ) )
            {
                fprintf( stderr, "input line exceeds maximum line length!\n" );
                exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //remove newline character from string
            buffer[--line_length] = '\0';
        }

        //allocate memory for new string and add to array
        lines[num_lines] = malloc( line_length + 1 );

        //verify that "malloc" succeeded
        if ( lines[num_lines] == NULL )
        {
            fprintf( stderr, "allocation error!\n" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        //copy line to newly allocated buffer
        strcpy( lines[num_lines], buffer );

        //increment counter
        num_lines++;
    }

    //All input lines have now been successfully read in, so
    //we can now do something with them.

    //handle one line per loop iteration
    for ( int i = 0; i < num_lines; i++ )
    {
        char *p, *q;

        //attempt to find the " ==== " marker
        p = strstr( lines[i], " ==== " );
        if ( p == NULL )
        {
            printf( "Warning: skipping line because unable to find \" ==== \".\n" );
            continue;
        }

        //skip the " ==== " marker
        p += 6;

        //split tokens on remainder of line using "strchr"
        while ( ( q = strchr( p, ' ') ) != NULL )
        {
            printf( "found token: %.*s\n", (int)(q-p), p );
            p = q + 1;
        }

        //output last token
        printf( "found token: %s\n", p );
    }

    //cleanup allocated memory
    for ( int i = 0; i < num_lines; i++ )
    {
        free( lines[i] );
    }
}
```

When running the program above with the following input

```
first line before deliminator ==== first line after deliminator
second line before deliminator ==== second line after deliminator
```

it has the following output:

```
found token: first
found token: line
found token: after
found token: deliminator
found token: second
found token: line
found token: after
found token: deliminator
```

If, however, there is no reasonable maximum number of lines known at compile-time, then the array `lines` will also have to be designed to grow in a similar way as `buffer` in the previous program. The same applies for the maximum line length.

Comment: Thank you so much for your clarification. However, I also need a buffer for the entire text for later use. That’s the purpose of char *text.

Comment: @RandomDev: Then you must ensure that `text` is large enough. If you do not know the required size of `text` in advance, then one thing you can do is to resize it using [`realloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc), when you run out of space. Under no circumstances should you write to `text` out of bounds, as this causes undefined behavior (it may cause your program to crash or misbehave in some way).

Comment: @RandomDev: Based on your commment, it seems that your main problem is to be to read in all of the input from `stdin` and store it as a string, when you do not know the length of the input in advance. I have therefore added a solution for this problem

Comment: @RandomDev: On second thought, instead of having one large string for the whole file, you may rather want an array of `char*` to the individual strings, each representing a line, so that for example `lines[0]` will be the string of the first line, `lines[1]` will be the string of the second line. That way, you can easily use `strtok` on each individual line. Is there a maximum number of lines that your program may assume? If not, then the array `lines` would also have to be programmed to grow on demand.

Comment: @RandomDev: I have now added a third piece of code, which probably does exactly what you want.